# Can't discard changes in git

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-stash, git-reset

A week or two ago I took some files that I had been archiving with a simple `find |sed|tar|xz|gpg` bash script, unpacked them all, and put their contents in a git repo, commited, put the next archives content in the repo, committed (rinse and repeat) in order to have a nicer system.

All files were edited with on one of my two computers, both using Arch Linux, in either TeXstudio or Vim.

I tried to checkout an old version, but its flipping out---it won't let me due to changed that are outstanding. I tried everything I knew how, and then went on Google to find out things I didn't know.

There are a number of other questions on this subject. Unfortunately their answers have not helped me. For sake of completion I'll list the questions.

> $ git status
> On branch master
> Changes not staged for commit:
> (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
> (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
>
> modified:   Arcs/arc1.tex
> modified:   Arcs/arc2.tex
> modified:   Arcs/frontmatter.tex
>
> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Also, so people don't need to look, below, I already did the obvious ones.

```
git reset --hard
git -a commit
git stash
git pull
```

as well as remove everything from the index and add it back.

## [Cant discard file changes in GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879788/cant-discard-file-changes-in-git)

I'm not on Windows. Also, this should have anything to do with line endings since I'm the only user. There is no reason for there to be weird line endings.

## [Git refuses to reset/discard files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536863/git-refuses-to-reset-discard-files/18875915)

```
git reset --hard HEAD (among other possibilities)
```

---

```
git stash
git stash drop
```

---

```
git config core.autocrlf input
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
git add .
git commit -m "Normalize line endings"
```

Not only did this not work but it increased the number of files that are misbehaving and also wrote 700+ lines to a file for. . .reasons. It wasn't even the file that was misbehaving.

## [Can't seem to discard changes in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575682/cant-seem-to-discard-changes-in-git)

More end line stuff.

## [How do I discard unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-i-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git)

```
git clean -df
git checkout -- .
git checkout -- ./.

git checkout-index -a -f

git checkout --force master
```

## Things I didn't see, but tried anyway

I tried commiting the changing `git commit -am "WORK DAMN YOU!"` then `git revert --hard HEAD^`

I also tried pulling from my private remote, but was just told that the local repo was already up to date.

This is extremely frustrating.

Comment: You've told us everything except what we really need to see, which is the output from `git status` at the very beginning when the problem began.  Can you include the original output from `git status`?

Comment: I omitted it since it seemed pretty banal. However, its up there now.

Comment: You have several options here.  If you _don't_ want those changes, you may do `git reset --hard` to discard them.  If you _do_ want the changes, then either follow Git's advice and `git add` followed by `git commit` them, or you can do a `git stash`.

Comment: I already did all of those.

Comment: Then I suggest that you made a mistake along the way.  The options I suggested all should have worked.

Comment: Indeed they should have. But they didn't. which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: So are you saying that after both a hard reset and/or a stash, `git status` is still showing files as being modified?

Comment: No. I'm saying that as soon as I do anything else, the whole circus starts all over. `Git stash` DOES clear the "errors" (for a time), but `git reset --hard` does nothing to fix this. Oops. Never mind. I'm wrong. `Git stash` ALSO does nothing. It stashes changes, but it doesn't clear the "error".

Comment: Then maybe something keeps modifying those files.  Close _all_ your text editors, IDEs, open files, etc., and then try doing a reset or stash.  This is the only explanation which comes to mind.

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen that something modifying the files behind your back is the most likely culprit. If you can't work out which program is doing this, try running `lsof +D .` within your working directory. If this doesn't help, you should inspect the output of `git diff` to see whether the changes in the working directory make sense (could also be helpful to add that output to the question if you're still at a loose end).

Comment: Make sure nothing has set `core.autocrlf` to anything (`true` is particularly wrong, but since you're on Linux you don't want it set). Make sure nothing has set `core.eol` either. Use `git config --get core.eol` and `git config --get core.autocrlf` to see what they are set to, if anything. Then, check for any files named `.gitattributes` that might set a *filter* for files named `*.tex` or `*.*` or whatever, as these could also do it. Check for unstable file systems or disk gremlins or processes eating your files behind your back, even if those are unlikely...

Comment: lsof +D came back negative. It was `.git/info/attributes`. Thanks @torek. If you want to write up an answer I'll mark it. Why was that having such an effect? And how should I fix that? Or should I make a new question asking that (after I do some research)? This is a problem in and of itself since I need those filters to make the LaTeX code more compatible with diff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717734/cant-discard-changes-in-git?noredirect=1#comment90419125_51717734):

> It was `.git/info/attributes`. ... Why was that having such an effect? ... I need those [`*.tex`] filters ...

You *can* use them.  You just have to be aware that Git doesn't *understand* them, and you may want to tweak them in some fashion.  Unfortunately there are few good alternatives for doing said tweaking.

The way that filters—called *clean* and *smudge* filters—work is directly related to the way that `core.autocrlf` and end-of-line mangling works.  To understand them yourself, start with a few simple facts:

- The content of any Git object—commit, tree, blob, or annotated tag—literally *cannot* be changed.  This is because the content is retrieved by its database key, which is a hash ID (currently SHA-1, in the future perhaps SHA-3 or some other very good hash) that *must match* the computed hash of the content.
- You retrieve a commit by its hash ID.  A branch name like `master` or `develop` just contains the actual hash ID of the latest commit on that branch.
- Each commit stores the raw hash ID of its parent commit, as part of its content, and stores the raw hash ID of the tree object that leads to the blob objects and thus produces the snapshot for that commit.

To store a new object into the database, you feed the object into `git hash-object -w` (or Git does this internally on its own).  Git *now computes* the hash of the content, including the header that gives the object's type and size, and stores the value—the content—into the database and emits the key.  You may then use the key in the future to retrieve the content.  At that time, Git *re-checks* the hash: it must match the key.  If it does not match, the data have been corrupted, and Git stops.

Hence, the commit hash must match the commit contents, which give the tree hash for the tree contents, which give the blob hashes for the blob contents.  If the commit is itself not the tip of a branch, the commit was found by walking back through a tip commit to some number of previous commits, all by their hash IDs.  The resulting data structure is a [Merkle Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) that provides Git's data-integrity guarantees.

This means that any filtering *cannot* be done on already-committed content.  And yet, it *must* be done on already-committed content, so that Windows users can have CRLF line endings, for instance.  How is Git to resolve this paradox?

The answer lies in another several facts about Git:

- You cannot work directly with commit contents.  They need to be extracted into a working area, called the *work-tree*.  The work-tree (or working tree or however you prefer to spell it) has the extracted files in de-compressed form, where they can be read and written.
- But Git adds an intermediate data structure as well, which Git originally just called the *index*.  This was not a very good name, so this data structure wound up with three names: it's the *index*, the *staging area*, and the *cache*.  This index keeps tabs on the work-tree, caching (hence the third name) `stat` system call data for instance.  Each file from the current commit is first extracted into the index, keeping it in its special compressed form—actually, just using the raw blob hash ID directly—so that the index has, or really, has a *reference to*, the copy of the file in the commit.
- Running `git add` on a file copies the file *into* the index (really, adding it as a blob object into the main database and computing its hash ID, then updating the hash ID in the index).  This means that the index is, at all times, the image that Git will use for the *next* commit you can make.  This is where it gets the name *staging area*.  Because you can overwrite index files with `git add`, they are writable here, where they are not writable in commits.
- Running `git commit` packages the current index into a tree object, freezing it for all time—the blob hashes are no longer changeable—and uses the tree object to make the new commit.

This index is how Git gets a lot of its speed, as compared to other version control systems.  Since the index keeps track of the work-tree, Git can do a lot of things much faster than usual: `git status`, for instance, can call `stat` on a directory or file and compare the result to cached `stat` data, without having to read the file itself.

(The index also takes on an expanded role during conflicted merges.  This isn't relevant to clean and smudge filters and LF/CRLF wars, but is worth mentioning while we're talking about the index.  Instead of just one entry per file-to-be-committed, the index can hold three not-to-be-committed entries: one from the merge base, and one from each of the two branch tips being merged.)

#### How filtering works

We are now ready to see how filtering really works.  Let's summarize the key points about commits, the index, and the work-tree:

- `git checkout` copies a commit's tree to the index, after which it exactly matches the commit's tree but in a form more suitable to keep track of the work-tree.
- `git checkout` *also* copies each commit's *file* to the work-tree, while updating the index slot for that file.
- `git add` copies a file from the work-tree back into the index, so that a future `git commit` can just freeze the index.

Now, remember, a *smudge filter* is applied to committed content, as it's turned into a work-tree file.  A *clean filter* is applied to work-tree content, as it's turned into committed—or at least, to-be-committed—content.  The smudge filter time is when LF-only line endings can become CRLF line endings for Windows users, and the clean filter time is when CRLF line endings can turn back to LF-only line endings.

***The ideal time to apply a smudge filter is while the file is being expanded***, i.e., copied from the index to the work-tree.  ***The ideal time to apply a clean filter is while the file is being compressed***, i.e., copied from the work-tree to the index.  So this is *when* Git does it.

At the same time, though, one of the key features of the index is *speed*.  So Git *assumes* that applying the smudge filter doesn't "change" the file, in some sense.  The content in the work-tree file may not match the decompressed blob any more, but—at least by intent and purpose—it still matches what you *would* get by cleaning and re-compressing the work-tree file.

The rub comes in when this *isn't* true.  What if cleaning and re-compressing the file results in different content, with a different hash ID?  The answer is that **Git may notice, and yet Git may not notice,** all depending on the vagaries of the effectiveness of the index-as-cache and the `stat` data saved in the index, vs the `stat` data delivered by a later system call.

If the smudge and clean filters are perfect mirrors—so that a smudged and re-cleaned file always matches the original—you can `git add` the file after extraction, and Git will update the saved `stat` data.  As long as that does not change again, Git will now believe that the file is clean.  If the underlying file system has unreliable `stat` data, you can use the index's *assume unchanged* bit to *force* Git to think that the file is clean anyway.  This is pretty crude and not a pleasing solution, but it will do the job.

Answer (score 7):

Try `git rm --cached -r .`

after `git reset --hard`

That was the only solution that worked for me.
Hope it will help somebody!

Comment: As mentioned that doesn't work. The copy stored in the repo is going to be different from the working copy due to filters. You can remove/replace the files all you want and in any way you want, but they will always disagree with what is stored in the commit.

Answer (score 2):

Try `git config --global core.autocrlf true`