# Trying to rebase to correct an attribute filter, but can't due to "unstaged changes"

Tags: git, rebase, gitattributes

## Problem

My cleaning filter failed to apply (a separate issue unrelated to Git) resulting in Git storing "dirty" files. I fixed the filter, but now I need to clean the files and then store them again.

## What is happening

I know from [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717734/cant-discard-changes-in-git) that if files were commited without a filter when there is an active filter present, no matter what I do those files will be seen as changed since the hashes will fail to match up. No ammount of `git reset --hard` or `git stash` will fix this, nor anything else.

## Failed solution

My first thought was to do an interactive rebase. However, even with `--force` it won't let me. With the force option, it simply says it can't be done, but without it Git complains about unstaged changes.

> cannot rebase: you have unstaged changes

## Unfruitful searches

I tried looking for a way to force Git to ignore unstaged changes, but all that lead to were the usual methods of HANDLING unstaged changes (ie `reset` and `stash`).

## What I'm in the midst of attempting

I'm currently trying to do the rebase manually, but for some reason it isn't working as expected. Its too soon to give more details than that, and its time for some lunch. I'm going mentioning this now since it came up in the comments.

## The only thing left as far as I can see.

The only solution I can think of is to set the current working directory aside, then `git reset --hard last-good-commit`. I'd then move the files back and commit, however I'd lose history, and I don't want that.

By "losing history" I mean the commits leading up to the "present" will be lost. I wish to avoid this.

## Question

How do force a rebase in this scenario?

Comment: (1) Why do you think you'd "lose history", and what do you think that means?  Please be concrete.  (2) What's wrong with stashing your unstaged work before doing unrelated cleanup and then popping the stash afterwards?  Please be concrete.

Comment: (1) if I git `reset --hard` I lose the history.  (2) as explained, stashing doesn't work. Its explained in detail in the linked question. As for what I mean by "lose the history" I mean that I lose the commits leading up to the present.

Comment: Why don't you just temporarily unset the filter driver and manually smudge/clean your working tree for the rebase?

Comment: I'm actually trying that right now, however it isn't going well. I should mention that.

Comment: I have never done this myself (I find clean and smudge filters deeply offensive to my "a VCS should save your bits unmodified" sensibilities -) ), but I would probably use @user3188445's approach too.

Comment: @Torek That's what I'm trying for, but for some reason Git is being disagreeable, though it hasn't exactly failed. It's neither succeeded nor failed yet. As for why I'm doing this, the files are LaTeX so I have long lines that I want to break up so there is one sentence per line. Git (and other VCS) can't properly diff/merge files when they are structured like that.

Comment: Ah. Yes, what's needed here is a different *merge driver* (that actually understands LaTeX). But that's a lot harder than some filter hackery...

Comment: Its not just merges though, its the delta compression too. I get better delta compression when Git isn't throwing out every line every time I type something. It makes the autoGit script I wrote(on write, if the last commit was 60s ago it commits, and pushes every 30-40 minutes depending on the number of pending commits) practical. Also, with these filters, a custom merge driver isn't needed (though desired for another reason: I want all merges to be marked as conflicting). It doesn't need to understand LaTeX, or that has been the result of my tests prior to putting these filters into practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to disable filters and then apply the filters manually as I rebase. As I had mentioned in the comments, there was a bit of a snag. That snag was that doing so resulted in empty commits. The solution to that was to remove the commit since it was an automated commit in the first place which is also the reason the filter wasn't applied.

## Further information

In ~/.bashrc I have a load path defined for the lib I wrote which is used by the filter scripts. The problem was that the automated git commit script was bypassing that environmental variable causing the cleaning script to fail. The solution to this was to specify the path to the lib explicitly in the script.